# Receive function parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, iframe

Is possible receive the parameters that were sent from the 
IFrame code behind (id and pTmp) the javascript popup then send them to the page parent

Code IFrame

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {
       EDPBLL = new EDPLogic();
       int id = EDPBLL.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["EDP"]), Convert.ToInt32(Session["userId"]), DateTime.Now, Convert.ToInt32(ddlPrensa.SelectedValue));
       string numeroEDP = EDPBLL.generarNumeroEDP(id);
       EDPBLL.UpdateEdpCode(id, numeroEDP);
       Session["pEDPId"] = id;
       Session["numeroEDP"] = numeroEDP;

       int pTmp = 4;

       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "Popup", "<script>Popup('"+id+"','"+pTmp+"')</script>", false);
    }
```

The script simulates a click event of parent window

Code JavaScript .aspx

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function Popup() {
            $("#MainContent_btnPrueba", window.parent.document).trigger("click");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please isolate your code in its simplest form with the iframe that you require. We don't necessarily need to see application specific code, just a simple, isolated example that shows what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Popup(var1, var2) {
            $("#MainContent_btnPrueba", window.parent.document).trigger("click");
        }
    </script>
```